# Handling DateTime column in DataExtenders

Tags: 2013, gui-extensions

We have data extender which will provide date when certain item is locked. Data extender adds column to Checked-out Items page. That is done by adding following XML block in ListCheckedOutItems.xml

```
<list:column id="LockedSince" type="data" title="{Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, LockedSince}" selector="@LockedSince"  enablefiltering="true" columnfilter="daterange"/>
```

This is part of code reads items with CoreService data and returns LockData value

```
if (coreServiceClient != null && coreServiceClient.Read(tcmUri, new ReadOptions() { LoadFlags = LoadFlags.Expanded }) is RepositoryLocalObjectData repositoryLocalObjectData && repositoryLocalObjectData.LockInfo.LockDate.HasValue)
{
    lockedSinceValue = repositoryLocalObjectData.LockInfo.LockDate.Value;
    coreServiceClient.Close();
}

return lockedSinceValue;
```

Problem is format of Date:

[image]

Is there any other way than converting DateTime value into string with certain format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this in ListCheckedOutItems.xml

```
<list:column id="LockedSince" type="data" title="{Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings, LockedSince}" selector="@LockedSince" translate="Tridion.Utils.Localization.TranslateDate"  enablefiltering="true" columnfilter="daterange" />
```